# crystal report showing question mark instead of text in arabic or persian language

Tags: crystal-reports

crystal report showing question mark instead of text in arabic or persian language like Photos shown below , arabic font is installed and other report is ok but this report was this problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Oax.jpg

[image: crystal report showing question mark]

thank you

Comment: Are you sure the font in the table body is the proper, Unicode one?

Comment: yes it is but i dont know why showing like this :-(

Comment: where do the values with question marks come from? can you show us the sql code that gets them?

Comment: {PKG_HEALTH_REPORT_SP_HEALTH_PAD_AGECONDITION27.NAME}+" "+{PKG_HEALTH_REPORT_SP_HEALTH_PAD_AGECONDITION27.FAMILY}

Comment: Unfortunately sql code not available